# How to reduce the time taken working on a big Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas, performance

I think my code is inefficient and I think there may be a way to do it better.

The objective of the code is that it takes an Excel listing and has to relate each element of a column to the rest of the elements of the same column. Depending on some conditions store it in a new data frame with the joint information, in my case the file has more than 16000 rows, so when doing the exercise it must perform (16.000 x 16.000) 256.000.000 iterations. But it takes days processing.

The code I have is the following:

```
import pandas as pd                                         
import numpy as np


excel1="Cs.xlsx"                                                 

dataframe1=pd.read_excel(excel1)                                

col_names=["Eb","Eb_n","Eb_Eb","L1","Ll1","L2","Ll2","D"]
my_df =pd.DataFrame(columns=col_names)                          

count_row = dataframe1.shape[0] 

print(count_row)

for n in range(0,count_row):

    for p in range(0,count_row):
        if abs(dataframe1.iloc[n,1] - dataframe1.iloc[p,1]) < 0.27 and abs(dataframe1.iloc[n,2] - 
            dataframe1.iloc[p,2]) < 0.27:           
            Nb_Nb=dataframe1.iloc[n,0]+"_"+dataframe1.iloc[p,0]     
            myrow=pd.Series([dataframe1.iloc[n,0],dataframe1.iloc[p,0],Nb_Nb,dataframe1.iloc[n,1],
            dataframe1.iloc[n,2],dataframe1.iloc[p,1],dataframe1.iloc[p,2]],   
            index=["Eb","Eb_n","Eb_Eb","L1","Ll1","L2","Ll2"])
            my_df = my_df.append(myrow, ignore_index=True)          
    
print(my_df.head(5))
```

Comment: What does "573/5000" mean?

Answer (score 0):

To start with, you can try using a different python structure. Dataframes take a lot of memory and are slower to process.

Order from simple structures and more efficient processing to complex structures and less efficient processing

1. Lists
2. Dictionaries
3. Numpy Arrays
4. Pandas Series
5. Pandas Dataframes

Comment: Depending on what they are used for, NumPy arrays and Pandas dataframes are more efficient to work with than lists and dictionaries.

Comment: @mkrieger1 - you are correct, the simplicity and efficiency comes with a cost. It will be necessary to weigh the pros and cons of either choice.